# Custom wpdb query for select post more than one taxonomy

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to write a custom select post query for wordpress. I'm using woocommerce. In woocommerce the default post type name is "product" and taxonomy name in "product_cat"
I've added another taxonomy names "spec" for product specification.

So in my product category assume "samsung", "laptop" is a term name for product category. and in "spec" I've some specification such as its "core i5 processor", "8gb ddr3 ram" etc. and my post title is "super notebook"

I want to search it for any of this field like if type notebook in my search field it will show all notebook. Underneath the search input type text area I also have a select box which has all "product_cat" there like samsung, hp, apple, laptop etc.

**Product title / Post title**

- Super notebook

**product_cat**

- samsung
- laptop

**spec**

- core i5 processor
- 8gb ddr3 ram

  global $wpdb;

  ```
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.*
              FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms
              WHERE (wp_terms.name LIKE '%ddr3 ram%'
                  OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%ddr3 ram%')
              AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
              AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
              AND wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
              AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
              AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id  GROUP BY  wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC";

  $object = $wpdb->get_results($query);

  _log($object);
  ```

I try this code it show the result.

But if I try this it'll not show the result

```
global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.*
                FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms
                WHERE (wp_terms.name LIKE '%ddr3 ram%'
                    AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%samsung%'
                    OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%ddr3 ram%')
                AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
                AND wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
                AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
                AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id  GROUP BY  wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC";

    $object = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    _log($object);
```

I don't have any idea to fix this. So anyone want to help me please give this answer for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.*
            FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms
            WHERE (wp_terms.name LIKE '%ddr3 ram%'
                OR wp_terms.name LIKE '%samsung%'
                OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%ddr3 ram%')
            AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
            AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
            AND wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
            AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
            AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id  GROUP BY  wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC";

$object = $wpdb->get_results($query);

_log($object);
```

Comment: I know OR but I've some dependency here. Because samsung is predefiend and fixed from the frontend and it should be. I've made a mistake to the question. ( AND wp_terms.name = 'samsung' ). and I also need an AND relation to meta key value meta_key = '_price' AND meta_value BETWEEN '1' AND '10'. Is there any better wp query you find? If you have any give me the link
Thanks.
Faysal